# How to concretize spack environnements on a machine without internet access?

Tags: spack

I want to use spack to install various packages and compile on a supercomputer that for all intents and purposes, doesn't have direct access to the internet. I can send files to this machine, like the spack repository or package archive but from the machine, I can't access the internet and thus can't just `spack install`.

My initial idea was to use create an spack environnement on the target machine and use `spack concretize` to freeze my dependencies and then use this concretize environnement to download the appropriate archives with `spack fetch` and then send them on the machine to do the compilation but `spack` needs to download and install `clingo` to work and cannot because of the lack of access to internet.

I tried to use the same approach for `clingo` but sadly the two machines I'm working on don't share the same architecture and thus I cannot concretize clingo against the architecture of the supercomputer on my laptop for example.

I am lost as to what could possibly fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your packages the preferred way to do this would be through creating a [mirror](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mirrors.html#mirrors-mirrors-yaml) that could then be transferred onto your system.

For the bootstrapping issue checkout [Bootstrapping for air gapped systems](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bootstrapping.html?highlight=bootstrap#creating-a-mirror-for-air-gapped-systems).  This is a newer feature that is essentially creating a mirror specifically for bootstrapping procedures.

It is also worth noting that if you can install `clingo` on your system's profile through any other means then you won't need to bootstrap it.  You run the risk of compatibility issues if you get the wrong version of `clingo` but it is another option.